# What am I doing wrong with gspreadsheets' vlookup formula?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

In google spreadsheets, I have the formula:

`=VLOOKUP("hello",'Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$65, 1)`

My expectation is that this would echo the value "hello" if it was found in Sheet1 in range C2:C65, and be null otherwise.  It instead gives the value from C35 ("hello" is found in C17 of Sheet1).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP returns #N/A where the formula is correct but the value sought is not present where searched for.

The fourth parameter for the function is optional but defaults to TRUE which may give incorrect results when the search column is not sorted.

[Ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

I think what you are doing wrong is 'instructing' the formula that the column to be searched is sorted in order when it is not. Sorting is critical for a binary search.

If you interpret [How to match info between tabs in a Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60888/how-to-match-info-between-tabs-in-a-google-spreadsheet/60893#60893) the same way as I did there is an example that works on Web Apps.